# can't merge down layers photoshop cs6?

Tags: 64-bit, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I have adobe Photoshop cs6 installed only the 64 bit I didn't install the  x86,
now I can't merge down layers I tried ctrl+D  but didn't work besides "merge down" command is dimmed

Comment: Do the layers have a lock sign?

Comment: Are you on a layer which is visible?

Comment: no, please have a look at this snapshot:
[http://s19.postimg.org/8qtrw997n/snapshot.jpg ]

Comment: Merge Layers does not become active unless you select (at least) two layers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>?

Or sometimes there's only 1 channel layer selected instead of all RGB layer selected (channel bar is beside the layer bar).

But from your screenshot it also looks like you're linking the selected layer with the layer down there?